# Can't burn to CD with any program in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: iso, dvd, cd, burning, brasero

I recently had to upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 (both running XFCe, if that makes any difference). The CD drive was working perfectly in the former, but I'm having issues with the latter. It reads discs just fine, but it won't burn to them.

K3B and Img Burn (through Wine) don't recognise any drives. Brasero does, but upon trying to burn an iso, it ejects the drivebefore it begins and comes up with an error. Here is the log.

```
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroBurnURI stopping
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroBurnURI output set (IMAGE) image = /tmp/brasero_tmp_5CCL81.bin toc = /tmp/brasero_tmp_5CCL81.cue
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroBurnURI no burn:// URI found
BraseroBurnURI stopping
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroLocalTrack stopping
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLocalTrack output set (IMAGE) image = /tmp/brasero_tmp_YNCL81.bin toc = /tmp/brasero_tmp_YNCL81.cue
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroLocalTrack no remote URIs
BraseroLocalTrack stopping
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroWodim getting varg
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroWodim got varg:
BraseroWodim deactivating
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroWodim getting varg
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_device
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_speed
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_input_type
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroWodim got varg:
    wodim
    -v
    dev=/dev/sr0
    speed=40
    driveropts=burnfree
    -dao
    fs=16m
    -text
    cuefile=/home/cobradile/Luchdaidhean a-nuas/ISOs/3DO Game Guru (USA, Europe).cue
BraseroWodim Launching command in /home/cobradile/Luchdaidhean a-nuas/ISOs
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroWodim stderr: scsidev: '/dev/sr0'
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroWodim stderr: devname: '/dev/sr0'
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroWodim stderr: scsibus: -2 target: -2 lun: -2
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroWodim stderr: Linux sg driver version: 3.5.27
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroWodim stderr: Wodim version: 1.1.11
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroWodim stderr: SCSI buffer size: 64512
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroWodim stderr: Beginning DMA speed test. Set CDR_NODMATEST environment variable if device
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroWodim stderr: communication breaks or freezes immediately after that.
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroWodim stdout: TOC Type: 1 = CD-ROM
BraseroWodim stderr: Unsupported sector size 2352 for data on line 3 in '/home/cobradile/Luchdaidhean a-nuas/ISOs/3DO Game Guru (USA, Europe).cue'.
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroWodim stdout: Driveropts: 'burnfree'
BraseroWodim stdout: Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
BraseroWodim stdout: Version        : 5
BraseroWodim stdout: Response Format: 2
BraseroWodim stdout: Capabilities   : 
BraseroWodim stdout: Vendor_info    : 'HL-DT-ST'
BraseroWodim stdout: Identification : 'BD-RE  WH16NS60 '
BraseroWodim stdout: Revision       : '1.03'
BraseroWodim stdout: Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.
BraseroWodim stdout: Current: 0x0009 (CD-R)
BraseroWodim stdout: Profile: 0x0043 (BD-RE) 
BraseroWodim stdout: Profile: 0x0042 (BD-R random recording) 
BraseroWodim stdout: Profile: 0x0041 (BD-R sequential recording) 
BraseroWodim stdout: Profile: 0x0040 (BD-ROM) 
BraseroWodim stdout: Profile: 0x002B (DVD+R/DL) 
BraseroWodim stdout: Profile: 0x001B (DVD+R) 
BraseroWodim stdout: Profile: 0x001A (DVD+RW) 
BraseroWodim stdout: Profile: 0x0016 (DVD-R/DL layer jump recording) 
BraseroWodim stdout: Profile: 0x0015 (DVD-R/DL sequential recording) 
BraseroWodim stdout: Profile: 0x0014 (DVD-RW sequential recording) 
BraseroWodim stdout: Profile: 0x0013 (DVD-RW restricted overwrite) 
BraseroWodim stdout: Profile: 0x0012 (DVD-RAM) 
BraseroWodim stdout: Profile: 0x0011 (DVD-R sequential recording) 
BraseroWodim stdout: Profile: 0x0010 (DVD-ROM) 
BraseroWodim stdout: Profile: 0x000A (CD-RW) 
BraseroWodim stdout: Profile: 0x0009 (CD-R) (current)
BraseroWodim stdout: Profile: 0x0008 (CD-ROM) 
BraseroWodim stdout: Profile: 0x0002 (Removable disk) 
BraseroWodim stdout: Using generic SCSI-3/mmc   CD-R/CD-RW driver (mmc_cdr).
BraseroWodim stdout: Driver flags   : MMC-3 SWABAUDIO BURNFREE 
BraseroWodim stdout: Supported modes: TAO PACKET SAO SAO/R96P SAO/R96R RAW/R16 RAW/R96P RAW/R96R
BraseroWodim stdout: Drive buf size : 3027200 = 2956 KB
BraseroWodim stdout: FIFO size      : 16777216 = 16384 KB
BraseroWodim stderr: HUP
BraseroWodim stdout: HUP
BraseroWodim process finished with status 1
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_error
BraseroWodim finished with an error
BraseroWodim asked to stop because of an error
    error       = 0
    message = "no message"
BraseroWodim stopping
Session error : unknown (brasero_burn_record brasero-burn.c:2859)
```

What do I do?

Comment: I think it has been a decade since the Ubuntu ISO fitted in a CD. You may need a DVD.

Comment: Sorry, I phrased the question wrong, I can't burn any CDs IN Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: I can't provide any useful advice sorry; but I last wrote a DVD in the *kinetic* cycle (ie. 22.10) & didn't have issues beyond hardware (ie. *drives failing as old.. I've had to replace 5 DVD writers in the last 3 years as most are getting old but that's a hardware issue*). The box I now use no longer has a optical writer, but I'd try using a different *blank* (I found 2-5 were damaged on a pack of 50 or 100) & then check your drive health (*last 3 issues I didn't even read logs; just swapped out drive & it replacement drive worked*). I used Xubuntu/Xfce though thus `xfburn` but k3b worked too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wodim arguments under "BraseroWodim got varg:" look somewhat overdone
for the task of burning an ISO image. I wonder from where the cuefile stems.
It seems to contain a bad instruction:

```
BraseroWodim stderr: Unsupported sector size 2352 for data on line 3 in '/home/cobradile/Luchdaidhean a-nuas/ISOs/3DO Game Guru (USA, Europe).cue'.
```

If you have a preformatted ISO image, then try on the command line

```
  wodim -v dev=/dev/sr0 speed=40 driveropts=burnfree -dao fs=16m ...path.to.iso.
image.file...
```

If your "ISO" is indeed a collection of content files and a CUE sheet,
then you will have to fix the CUE sheet.

Comment: Okay, brasero burns different isos. ImgBurn through wine still doesn't recognise any drives, though?

Comment: Nevermind, insalled it through PlayOnLinux, it works as intended now, thank you so much!